# Dynamically created <th> get's lower position why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the code snippet where I've created `<th>` using jquery.

My question is, How can I place the dynamically created `<th>` above the two `<td>`'s which I've created below.

I've tried to search a lot but all the results where adding to the end only, not to the top of the `<td>`.

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    var noOfRow = document.getElementById("addItemTable").rows.length;
    var temp = document.getElementById("addItemTable");
    var table = temp.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML="this is inside table div";
    cell2.style="border: dashed;"
    cell3.innerHTML="this is inside another another div";
    cell3.style="border: dashed;"
    var thContent = '<th class="col2">' + '<br>' + 'test' + '&nbsp &nbsp' + '*' + '' + '</th>'
    var mainTable = document.getElementById("addItemTable");
    $('#addItemTable>tbody>tr').append(thContent);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-content" id="elementDiv">
  <table id="addItemTable">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You **must** insert a new row, preferrably inside a `thead` if it's a `th`. If for whatever reason you must do it in `tbody`, use `tbody.insertBefore(tbody.firstElementChild, newRow)`. Remember that all rows in a table must have the same number of cells (colspan potentially decreasing the number necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use prepend insead of append :)

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    var noOfRow = document.getElementById("addItemTable").rows.length;
    var temp = document.getElementById("addItemTable");
    var table = temp.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML="this is inside table div";
    cell2.style="border: dashed;"
    cell3.innerHTML="this is inside another another div";
    cell3.style="border: dashed;"
    var thContent = '<th class="col2">' + '<br>' + 'test' + '&nbsp &nbsp' + '*' + '' + '</th>'
    var mainTable = document.getElementById("addItemTable");
    $('#addItemTable>tbody>tr').prepend(thContent);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-content" id="elementDiv">
  <table id="addItemTable">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```