# Cannot understand the behavior prepend method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used code to create a `<th>`, This below code works fine for the first time but doesn't work when i create them repeatedly,i.e, Again and again.

```js
function createTH(){
  var noOfRow = document.getElementById("addItemTable").rows.length;
    var temp = document.getElementById("addItemTable");
    var table = temp.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML="this is inside table div";
    cell2.style="border: dashed;"
    cell3.innerHTML="this is inside another another div";
    cell3.style="border: dashed;"
    var thContent = '<th class="col2">' + '<br>' + 'test' + '&nbsp &nbsp' + '*' + '' + '</th>'
    var mainTable = document.getElementById("addItemTable");
    $('#addItemTable>tbody>tr').prepend(thContent);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-content" id="elementDiv">
  <table id="addItemTable">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="createTH()" value="Click to create <th> again and again"/>
```

My current output is a mess after doing the second click on the button.

My expected output is in following pattern:

```
<tr>
...
<th><td><td>//I only want to repeat this single line on every click of button.
<th><td><td>
<th><td><td>//I'm looking to create this kind of repetition on click of button. 
...
</tr>
```

For more reference you can visit: [Dynamic Creation of th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58748709/dynamically-created-th-gets-lower-position-why), as this question is continuation of the above mentioned thread. I made a new thread because old thread would become more tedious and the length of question would be increased.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why create `<td></td>` inside a `<th>`? It is syntactically wrong.

Comment: @Andrew the OP is prepending the `th` to the row, not the td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're appending `thContent` to *all* `tr` which you select by jQuery, not just the new one. To fix this change the line to only append to the new `row` instance:

```
$(row).prepend(thContent);
```

However it's worth noting that you're using an odd combination of plain JS and jQuery. If you're using jQuery already you can simplify the code drastically:

```js
$('#add').on('click', function() {
  var rowHtml = '<tr><th class="col2"><br />test&nbsp; &nbsp;*</th><td>this is inside table div</td><td>this is inside another another div</td></tr>';
  $('#addItemTable').append(rowHtml);
});
```

```css
td { border: dashed; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-content" id="elementDiv">
  <table id="addItemTable">
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="add">Click to create &lt;th&gt; again and again</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You keep adding to every row.

Use jQuery consistently and it helps. Also DRY: Do not repeat yourself

Like this

```js
const cellStyle = { "style": "border: dashed;" }

$("#addRow").on("click", function() {
  const $tb = $("#addItemTable tbody");
  let $newRow = $("<tr/>");
  $newRow.append('<th class="col2"><br />test&nbsp;&nbsp;*</th>');
  $newRow.append($("<td/>", cellStyle).text("this is inside table cell"));
  $newRow.append($("<td/>", cellStyle).text("this is inside another table cell"));
  $tb.prepend($newRow);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-content" id="elementDiv">
  <table id="addItemTable">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<input type="button" id="addRow" value="Click to create <tr> again and again" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row counter to increase index number of row and append data in it when function calls.

**Here is Demo**

```js
var rowCounter = 0;
function createTH(){
  var noOfRow = document.getElementById("addItemTable").rows.length;
    var temp = document.getElementById("addItemTable");
    
    var table = temp.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML="this is inside table div";
    cell2.style="border: dashed;"
    cell3.innerHTML="this is inside another another div";
    cell3.style="border: dashed;"
    var thContent = '<th class="col2">' + '<br>' + 'test' + '&nbsp &nbsp' + '*' + '' + '</th>'
    var mainTable = document.getElementById("addItemTable");
    $('#addItemTable>tbody>tr').eq(rowCounter).prepend(thContent);
    rowCounter++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-content" id="elementDiv">
  <table id="addItemTable">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="createTH()" value="Click to create <th> again and again"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one more solution for this question by making use of ***Outer Html***. Just a different approach to this problem.

```js
function createTH() {
  var noOfRow = document.getElementById("addItemTable").rows.length;
  var temp = document.getElementById("addItemTable");
  var table = temp.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  elemVal = '<th class="col2">' + "test" + '&nbsp &nbsp' + '*' + '' + '</th>';
  cell1.outerHTML = elemVal;
  cell2.innerHTML = "this is inside table div";
  cell2.style = "border: dashed;"
  cell3.innerHTML = "this is inside another another div";
  cell3.style = "border: dashed;"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m-content" id="elementDiv">
  <table id="addItemTable">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="createTH()" value="Click to create <th> again and again" />
```